# get the value selected in dropdownlist in spring mvc hibernate mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-annotations

Hi i am writing an application in spring mvc hibernate annotation.Here two tables are used one for keeping employee detail(Employee table) and another for keeping team detail(Team table).
Here i am using drop down box in my jsp to select the team name so as to display all the employee belong to that team.But i am stuck here i can't get the  selected team.What i want to do is when i select a team, eg team1 i want to display all employees belongs to team1.

My jsp snippet for selecting the team name from mysql database and here the dropdown list shows all the tean name from team table

myjsp

```
  <tr>
            <td>
                            <form:label path="teams.teamId">Team Name</form:label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="teams.teamId" cssStyle="width: 150px;">    
                                <option value="-1">Select a type</option>
                                <c:forEach items="${teamKey}" var="teams">
                                <option value="${teams.teamId}">${teams.teamName}</option>

                                </c:forEach>



                            </form:select>




        </tr>
```

hibernate select query used in resourceDao implentation class

```
@Override
public void serchResources(int teamid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("teamid is given----------  :"+teamid);
    sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Resource WHERE teamId=" +teamid);


    System.out.println("After query  teamid is given--*************  :"+teamid);

}
```

controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/searchResult",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView searchResult(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource,BindingResult result){
    resourceServices.serchResources(resource.getTeams().getTeamId());
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("resourcekey",resourceServices.listResources());
    model.put("teamKey", addteamServices.listTeams());

    return new  ModelAndView("Search",model);
}
```

Console

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.resource.ResourceController.ResourceController.searchResult(ResourceController.java:130)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

please help...
thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the error Any stacktrace?

Comment: can you please also put the console output that you are getting... also i would advice you to put a debug point and inspect all the elements you are using... that way, you will be more sure as to where the problem is exactly happening... please provide the console output... possible issue could be that, you are getting a list in your model. so handle the list with an iterator.

Comment: @DeepakRShankar hi provided the stack trace

Comment: @DanglingPiyush provided the stack trace

Comment: I guess `public ModelAndView searchResult(@ModelAttribute("command") Resource resource,BindingResult result)` here, the resource is becoming null... so any operation you try to do on that object, you are getting a null pointer exception. make sure you are sending the valid object to your `searchResult` method.

Comment: You must initialize Resource.teams to a non null value in Resource default constructor as it is the constructor that will be user by Spring.